# bzr equivalent of svn mergeinfo

Tags: svn, bazaar

In my current svn repository I use the command:

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ^/trunk ^/branches/testing
```

to get revisions to merge in a format processable by a program.

Does someone know if there is an equivalent command in bazaar?

Answer (score 1):

The way `bzr` works, I don't think there's an exact equivalent to `svn mergeinfo`, however, the information that you seek should be retrievable by the `bzr missing` command, specifically:

```
cd /path/to/trunk
bzr missing --line --theirs-only /path/to/branches/testing | tail + 2 | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

The `--theirs-only` option shows revisions that exist in the other branch but haven't been merged into the current one. The `tail +2` filter strips out the header line.

The `--line` format will have additional information that `awk` then strips out by only printing the revision number before the colon.

You can also omit the `cd` part in an automated script by using the `-d` option if desired:

```
bzr missing --line --theirs-only -d /path/to/trunk /path/to/branches/testing
```

If you need more information instead of just the revision number (for example, if you need UUIDs instead of numeric revision numbers), you can install the bzr-xmloutput plugin via:

```
# create ~/.bazaar/plugins directory if it doesn't exist via
# mkdir ~/.bazaar; mkdir ~/.bazaar/plugins
cd ~/.bazaar/plugins
bzr branch lp:bzr-xmloutput xmloutput
```

and use `--xml --show-ids` instead of `--line` and use your favorite XML library to process the output.